# Where is the crawled data stored when running nutch crawler?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am new to Nutch. I need to crawl the web (say, a few hundred web pages), read the crawled data and do some analysis.

I followed the link https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial (and integrated Solr since I may require to search text in future) and ran the crawl using a few URLs as the seed.

Now, I don't find the `text/html` data in my local machine.  Where can I find the data and what is the best way to read the data in text format?

#### Versions

- apache-nutch-1.9
- solr-4.10.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After your crawl is over, you could use the bin/nutch dump command to dump all the urls fetched in plain html format.

The usage is as follows :

```
$ bin/nutch dump [-h] [-mimetype <mimetype>] [-outputDir <outputDir>]
   [-segment <segment>]
 -h,--help                show this help message
 -mimetype <mimetype>     an optional list of mimetypes to dump, excluding
                      all others. Defaults to all.
 -outputDir <outputDir>   output directory (which will be created) to host
                      the raw data
 -segment <segment>       the segment(s) to use
```

So for example you could do something like

```
$ bin/nutch dump -segment crawl/segments -outputDir crawl/dump/
```

This would create a new dir at the -outputDir location and dump all the pages crawled in html format.

There are many more ways of dumping out specific data from Nutch, have a look at https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/CommandLineOptions

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did it in a different way. There is a file namely 'data' inside "segments/2*************/content/part-00000" folder, and it is a sequential file.  I wrote a java program to convert it into text.  Your answer is pretty straightforward and very informative.

Comment: how to get for nutch2